# Converter tratar variável nula usando a propriedade length em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma aplicação onde me surgiu uma dúvida. Nessa aplicação pode haver em algum momento uma variável onde o valor dela deveria ser uma string vazia (**""**) mas, como sou obrigado a trabalhar com outra equipe onde não tenho total conhecimento do projeto, dependendo da situação o retorno pode ser **null**.

Hoje, com todo o conhecimento que alcancei, só consigo pensar em usar uma condição multipla caso isso ocorra, como no código abaixo

```
var teste;
if(teste === null || teste.length == 0){
  return true;
}
```

existe alguma forma de eu validar este `teste === null` de uma forma mais "bonita"?

**NOTA**: bonita eu digo mais legível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe uma maneira mais simples e legível (minha opinião) para retornar isso, basta usar o operador unário de negação (!). No JS existem valores que são considerados `falsy`, que durante uma operação que aplica coerção para booleano, ele considera essa tabela de valores `falsy` para considerar o valor como um falso. Tanto string vazia como `null` são valores considerados `falsy`, então a negação desses valores resulta em verdadeiro. Para retornar basta fazer assim:

```
return !teste;
```

Você pode ver [aqui](https://ericdouglas.github.io/2014/04/19/14-javascript-furtivo-o-valor-dos-tipos-de-operadores-parte-02/) as aplicabilidades dos valores `truthy` e `falsy` da linguagem. Caso queira algo mais "completo", que explica bastante detalhes de como funciona diversas operações do JS, inclusive usando o próprio JS como exemplo, você pode ver na encyclopedia escrita pelo Crockford. Inclusive [existe uma parte que fala](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/#falsy) dos valores `falsy` da linguagem. Eu acho razoavelmente completo essa wiki do Crockford, recomendo.

Comment: excelente!, muito obrigado!